# Cannot convert google map to image using html2canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I tried to convert google map to image using hml2canvas. But it didn't help me. I got an empty png file. Please help.

I tried few solutions but it didn't work for me
https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/145#issuecomment-11449761
http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/j17mwmjm/

I'm not able to use google static API because I generate google map from kml file and have lot of coordinates which exceeds the GET Url limits.

```js
    <div id="map-canvas" style="height: 500px;"></div>
    <div id="maptoimage"><img id="imagemap" src="" /></div>
     <script>
        html2canvas($("#map-canvas"), {
        seCORS: true,
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            theCanvas = canvas;
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);

            // Convert and download as image 
            Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas);
            // to show the generated image in div
            $("#maptoimage").append(canvas);
            // Clean up 
            //document.body.removeChild(canvas);
        }
     });
     </script>
```

The google map is loaded in map-canvas div.

Comment: Where is your code? The fiddle you shared works for me, so what is not working? Your question is totally unclear.

Comment: @MrUpsidown, This is the piece of code in have tried and I get an empty PNG file when downloaded.

Comment: Well... I don't. I see the exact same map as a PNG file, which I can download and open: https://i.imgur.com/raCdHzP.png

Comment: The URL you are using in your fiddle for canvas2image is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working code snippet with which I get a valid and readable PNG file with the appropriate `.png` extension and a custom filename.

```js
function initMap() {

  var map;
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.241943, -122.889318);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: latlng,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);
}

function saveAs(uri, filename) {

  var link = document.createElement('a');

  if (typeof link.download === 'string') {

    link.href = uri;
    link.download = filename;

    //Firefox requires the link to be in the body
    document.body.appendChild(link);

    //simulate click
    link.click();

    //remove the link when done
    document.body.removeChild(link);
  } else {
    window.open(uri);
  }
}

$(function() {
  $("#btnSave").click(function() {
    html2canvas($("#map-canvas"), {
      useCORS: true,
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
        saveAs(canvas.toDataURL(), 'my-cool-filename.png');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>

<script src="https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases/download/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/canvas2image@1.0.5/canvas2image.min.js"></script>

<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>

<input type="button" id="btnSave" value="Save PNG" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working in my windows chrome browser, the only issue is that the downloaded image file has no extension, but it works when I rename it and add `.png`

Note that you have a typo and are missing an `u` at `useCORS`, this prevents some images from being loaded.

```js
$(function () {
  html2canvas($("#map-canvas"), {
    useCORS: true,
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      document.body.appendChild(canvas);

      // Convert and download as image 
      Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas);
      // to show the generated image in div
      $("#maptoimage").append(canvas);
      // Clean up 
      //document.body.removeChild(canvas);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/canvas2image@1.0.5/canvas2image.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Original:
<div id="map-canvas"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/raCdHzP.png"></div>
Copy:
<div id="maptoimage"></div>
```