# Can't take google maps snapshot with html2canvas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, html2canvas

I'm trying to use html2canvas to take a snapshot of Google Maps with html2canvas. Im using html2canvas v 1.0.0-rc.3 and Google Maps API. It works fine in both Edge and Firefox but throws error in Chrome.

The error:
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The image argument is a canvas element with a width or height of 0.

The problem seems to be Google Chrome related since it works with both in Firefox and Edge. I know it works fine if I use HTML/JS (or jQuery) but since Im using React it throws the error mentioned.

```
function App() {

function takeScreenshot() {
    const clickBtn = document.getElementById('theMap');
    html2canvas(clickBtn, {
      allowTaint: false,
      useCORS: true,
    }).then(canvas => {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
   });
  }

return (
    <div className="App">
      <div id="app">
        <button id="screenshot" onClick={() => takeScreenshot()}>
          Take screenshot html2canvas
        </button>
      </div>
      <div id="theMap">
        <Map />
      </div>
     </div>
 );
}
```

maps Comp

```
export default function Map({ options, onMount, className }) {
  const props = { ref: useRef(), className };
  const onLoad = () => {
    const map = new window.google.maps.Map(props.ref.current, options);
    onMount && onMount(map);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!window.google) {
      const script = document.createElement(`script`);
      script.type = `text/javascript`;
      const API = 'API_KEY';
      script.src = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? 
 key=${API}&callback=resolveGoogleMapsPromise`;
      const headScript = document.getElementsByTagName(`script`)[0];
      headScript.parentNode.insertBefore(script, headScript);
      script.addEventListener(`load`, onLoad);
      return () => script.removeEventListener(`load`, onLoad);
    } else onLoad();
  });

  return (
    <div
      {...props}
      style={{
        height: `300px`,
        width: `400px`,
        margin: `1em 0`,
        borderRadius: `0.5em`
      }}
      id="map"
    />
  );
}

Map.defaultProps = {
  options: {
    center: { lat: 48, lng: 8 },
    zoom: 5
  }
};
```

I expect it to be able to work as it does in both Edge and Firefox

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot convert google map to image using html2canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56884126/cannot-convert-google-map-to-image-using-html2canvas)

Comment: The problem seems to be Google Chrome related since it works with both in Firefox and Edge. I know it works fine if I use HTML/JS (or jQuery) but since Im using React it throws the error mentioned.

Comment: It looks like this issue has been reported on [GitHub](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/1859) and [this PR](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/pull/1863) fixes it. Can you please confirm if that works for you?

Comment: @evan No, It didn't work for me but I got it to work last week. I used  `html2canvas(document.querySelector('#page-content-wrapper'),
      {
        allowTaint: false,
        useCORS: true,
        ignoreElements: function (node) {
          return node.nodeName === 'IFRAME';
        }
      })`

Comment: I see, glad to hear! Thanks for your update.